# How to create an unstoppable service in react native

Tags: react-native

I developed messenger in react-native using socket-io-client
now, I want to create an unstoppable service for message listener when my app in background or killed
Please help me how to create an unstoppable service in react -native

Comment: Could this be of help? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android#the-js-api

Comment: this is only for android i want to both ios and android